# html/css: strictly wrap the contents and not empty spaces

Tags: html, css

when I place a div with an id, around tables, it seems to capture a lot of empty padding to the left of the table it contains. How can I shrink wrap the div so that it's width will not include empty spaces? I want the div width and height to be exactly the size of it's content and have no empty spaces.

```
<style type="text/css">table {border-collapse: collapse;} td {padding: 3px} table, th, td { border: 3px solid black;} </style>
<div id="container">
<table><tbody><tr><td>Also serving Ida, ON</td><td>2</td><td>Map &amp; directions</td><td>416-748-5803</td><td>Website</td><td>5235 Steeles Ave W, North York, ON M9L\xa02W2</td><td>(1 review)</td><td>Car Alarm Systems</td><td>Car Radios &amp; Stereo Systems</td><td>Auto Alarm &amp; Sound Inc</td><td>Map &amp; directions</td><td>Category:</td><td>Be the first to review</td><td>, </td><td>Car Alarm Systems</td><td>3</td><td>Tint King</td><td>2450 Finch Ave W, North York, ON M9M\xa02E9</td><td>Map &amp; direct the first to review</td><td>, </td><td>Car Alarm Systems</td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td>Start-It-Smart Automation Inc</td><td></td><td></td><td>1151 Eglinton Ave E, Mississauga, ON L4W\xa01K6</td><td>Map &amp; directions</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Be the first to review</td><td>Category:</td><td>Car Alarm Systems</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><t></td></tr><tr><td></td><td>Locksmith &amp; Locks</td><td></td><td></td><td>10 Central Ave, Ottawa, ON K2P\xa00M9</td><td>MBA Audio &amp; Custom</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Be the first to review</td><td>Category:</td><td>Car Radios &amp; Stereo Systems</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table>'], [2, u"<table><tbody><tr><td>MBA Audio &amp; Custom</td><td></td><td>40 Russett Ave, Oshawa, ON L1G\xa03R5</td><td>(1 review)Car Radios &amp; Stereo Systems</td><td>Auto Sound Design &amp; Car Audio</td><td></td><td></td><td>Map &amp; directions</td><td></td><td></td><td>Website</td><td>Category:</td><td>Be the first to review</td></tr><tr><td>Affordable Lock Services Inc</td><td></td><td>88 Centre St N, Oshawa, ON L1G\xa04B6</td><td></td><td>\xa0</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Map &amp; directions</td><td>Category:</td><td>Website</td></tr><tr><td>Be the first to review</td><td></td><td>337 Simcoe St S, Oshawa, ON L1H\xa04H9</td><td></td><td>Locksmith &amp; Locks</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Seq Security Systems</td><td>Category:</td><td>\xa0</td></tr><tr><td>Map &amp; directions</td><td>705-930-0296</td><td>Peterborough Byps, Peterborough, ON</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Be the first to review</td><td>Security Control Systems &amp; Equipment</td><td>Category:</td><td>Self Stor</td></tr><tr><td>\xa0</td><td></td><td>ON</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Map &amp; directions</td><td></td><td>Website</td><td>Category:</td><td>Be the first to review<y location</td><td>Browse by video</td><td>Find on a map</td><td>Category:</td><td>Top businesses</td></tr><tr><td>Smart Tips</td><td></td><td>24 Steinway Blvd, Etobicoke, ON M9W\xa06T8</td><td></td><td>YellowPages.ca apps</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Gadgets and tools</td><td>Category:</td><td>Follow-us on Twitter</td></tr><tr><td>Facebook fan page</td><td>905-458-6828</td><td>1625 Steeles Ave E, Brampton, ON L6T\xa04T7</td><td></td><td>Shopwise</td><td>Canada411.ca</td><td></td><td></td><td>CanadaPlus.ca</td><td>homeTRADER.ca</td><td>RFD Forums</td><td>Category:</td><td>RedFlagDeals.com</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>

<div id="container">
<table><tbody><tr><td>2</td><td>Map &amp; directions</td><td>416-748-5803</td><td>Website</td><td>5235 Steeles Ave W, North York, ON M9L\xa02W2</td><td>(1 review)</td><td>Car Alarm Systems</td><td>Car Radios &amp; Stereo Systems</td><td>Auto Alarm &amp; Sound Inc</td><td>Map &amp; directions</td><td>Category:</td><td>Be the first to review</td><td>, </td><td>Car Alarm Systems</td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr>d>905-458-6828</td><td>1625 Steeles Ave E, Brampton, ON L6T\xa04T7</td><td></td><td>Shopwise</td><td>Canada411.ca</td><td></td><td></td><td>CanadaPlus.ca</td><td>homeTRADER.ca</td><td>RFD Forums</td><td>Category:</td><td>RedFlagDeals.com</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried

Comment: The best way would be to share the code you have written.

Comment: You cannot have **multiple** `ID` in one document. Use classnames `.container`

Comment: And what's the `<t>` tag for?

Comment: the tag closing opening mismatch and many typo errors exist in your html

Comment: What's the comma for? `<td>,</td>` You cannot have anything in between.

Comment: What is `<tr>d>905-458-6828</td>` ??

Comment: I don't see any problem with spacing but only with the html you have provided check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/yuLq7/

Comment: What on earth should `</tr></td>` be?

Comment: `review<y location`. What's that `<`?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/olEpONU/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can float the div. `float:left;`

Or display the div as a inline-block element: `display:inline-block;`

Also make sure padding and margins are set to 0 on the table and div, `margin:0; padding:0;`

Comment: IE is mean in confronts of `DIV` with `inline-block`